# Github on Pull Request Merge do a POST to my app

Tags: events, github, hook

Hey so I see I have a main repo and then a development fork of the repo. I work of the dev and submit pull request for code review to the main, if it gets accepted my boss will merge my pull request with the main repo.  We want to set up an even hook similar to "Post-Recieve URLs" that will send a post to my main web app once a pull request is accepted to do a `git pull`.  If I have this right "Post-Recieve URLs" only works for if I commit directly to the repository is that correct? So it wont work if I merge a pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have this right "Post-Recieve URLs" only works for if I commit directly to the repository is that correct?

Yes, so not activated in case of merge done directly within the repo.
And [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-07/msg00552.html) mentions that a "hook on merge" (ie on the auto-commit done by a merge) might not work.

A background job in charge of monitoring any new commits (and check if that commit is the result of a merge, by looking at its parent: more than one parent means "merge") is more appropriate.